# Is Gemfire free?

Tags: gemfire

I can see Gemfire is available for download at https://network.pivotal.io/products/pivotal-gemfire#/releases/2804/file_groups/500.

Will I have to pay once I download and install it? Can I use it without restrictions and without professional support?

What features does it have in addition to what is provided in the open source Apache Geode?

What is the license cost if I have to purchase Pivotal Gemfire?

Comment: "solely for use in a non-production environment for the Evaluation Period". Anyway, you would be better asking that question on Gemfire specific list on their site, rather than on SO.

Answer (score 4):

Pivotal Gemfire is not free, but if you are not using Gemfire as part of an enterprise, then Apache Geode is the same technology.  Currently the newest version of Pivotal Gemfire is based on the open source core of Apache Geode(which as of today is a top level Apache project).

The features you would get from buying from Pivotal would be enterprise support, indemnification, etc.  But right now Apache Geode has all features that Gemfire has including some new features like a redis adapter.

You can learn more about Geode and get started with it here. 
http://geode.apache.org/

Comment: thanks for the answer, mross. been noob at caching, 
i've registered at pivotal a couple of days ago and tried to download Gemfire without success and still don't have answer from support.
i think Geode or Hazelcast would suit all my needs.